# How to point to a pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a way to point to the pointer variable instead of it's address space so that it can be changed to NULL. Something like this. Apologies for the poor question I can't think of a better way of expressing what I'm trying to do.
Thanks.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *r;
    struct Node *l;
} Node;

Node* del(Node *N, int v)
{
    Node *n = N;
    Node **p = NULL;

    while (n != NULL)
    {
        if (something)
        {
            p = n.r;
            n = n->r;
        }
        else {
            p = n.l;
            n = n->l;
        }

        free(n);
        *p = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&` on a pointer just like on any other variable.  In your case, it looks like you might want to change `del` to:

```
Node *del(Node **N, int v)
```

And then call it like:

```
x = del(&someNode, 12);
```

Comment: And dereference with an additional *.

Comment: and use all the other regular pointer ops for the most part. Nested pointers are a very... fun thing :)